# JDBC generated key from insert on duplicate

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

If you have an insert with an ON DUPLICATE KEY clause, and there is a duplicate key, is there any way to get back the primary key that was duplicated? or do I have to do my own manual query? As far as I can tell getGeneratedKeys() from the CallableStatement class will not return as a new insert wasn't actually done.

EDIT
Sorry if it wasn't clear but I want to get the PRIMARY KEY of the record back.

So if I were have the following table (excuse syntax, just typing it freehand):

```
CREATE TABLE some_table(
  id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  value varchar(500)NOT NULL,
  count int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY (value)
);

INSERT INTO some_table(value) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1;
```

If I were to add 'test' as the value, a new record would be added and the id would be returned by getGeneratedKeys();

If I were to attempt to add 'test' again, the key already exists and therefore the count would be updated. What I want is the primary key/id of that row which was updated. Do I have to see that I get no results back from getGeneratedKeys() - as none where generated - and do another select after the fact?

Comment: Surely you know the duplicate because it's in the statement you've just executed?

Comment: Can you give us an example where you _wouldn't_ know what the key was prior to attempting the insert? It doesn't seem like that could happen...

Comment: Sorry - I should have been more clear I guess. I want the primary key of the table back.

Comment: Edited original for clarity

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1, id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)
```

Note: This shouldn't be necessary as of MySQL 5.5.

Comment: That doesn't help me at all, I would still have to do an extra query to get back the id. I was trying to do it all in one step.

Comment: I believe `getGeneratedKeys()` would now return the key you're looking for.

Comment: @MrZorn Did you try it?